# Error when trying to start logKitty for React-Native Android Project

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I have run this logger in other projects without issue running `react-native log-android` why is the logger failing in this project folder.  These are mostly out of box `react-native init NewProjects` with very few changes.  So im surprised this one project I can't run the logger in.  I like the cmd logger better.  Its faster than running the one in chrome.

```
λ react-native log-android
info Starting logkitty
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
error Command failed: 'C:\Users\{UserPIN}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb' logcat -c
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: 'C:\Users\{UserPIN}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb' logcat -c
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

    at spawnLogcatProcess (c:\ws\mobile2\ReactRegLoc\node_modules\logkitty\build\android\adb.js:36:11)
    at runAndroidLoggingProcess (c:\ws\mobile2\ReactRegLoc\node_modules\logkitty\build\android\adb.js:21:10)
    at logkitty (c:\ws\mobile2\ReactRegLoc\node_modules\logkitty\build\api.js:137:85)    at Object.logAndroid [as func] (c:\ws\mobile2\ReactRegLoc\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\logAndroid\index.js:37:44)
    at Command.handleAction (c:\ws\mobile2\ReactRegLoc\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:21)
    at Command.listener (c:\ws\mobile2\ReactRegLoc\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Command.parseArgs (c:\ws\mobile2\ReactRegLoc\node_modules\commander\index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (c:\ws\mobile2\ReactRegLoc\node_modules\commander\index.js:474:21)
    at setupAndRun (c:\ws\mobile2\ReactRegLoc\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:210:24)
```

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: Bug report submitted here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26198

Comment: Right now i just run log kitty from the projects folders where the path seems to work. You don't have to be in the folder of your project your running, log kitty just needs to be running so you get your logs for any running projects at that point.   I will look at the bug report @Reid.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems broken for right now, but a temporary fix is to change the file in your node-modules folder.

In node_modules/logkitty/build/android/adb.js

Change line 29 to:

```
return process.env.ANDROID_HOME ? `${process.env.ANDROID_HOME}\\platform-tools\\adb` : 'adb';
```

And change line 34 to:

```
(0, _child_process.execSync)(`${adbPath} logcat -c`);
```

Comment: Here's temporary lib with this fix, seems working: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@talaikis/logkitty

Comment: Sorry for delay on trying this.  This fix works.  Accepted and upvoted.

Comment: Does anyone maintain React-Native? There's been a solution posted here for over a month, and they just aren't releasing the fixed version?